# Why won't my SQL Server database show any results while running stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

Please look at the code I created. The first block is my stored procedure that I created.

The second block is me running the code manually, bypassing the stored procedure.

The 3rd block is me running the code using the stored procedure.

When I run the code without the stored procedure, I get results. When I run the code via the stored procedure, I don't get anything, even though it's presumably the same code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCheckSaleVIN] 
    @VIN nvarchar(17)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Sales
    WHERE VIN = @VIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM Sales
    WHERE (VIN = 09872345098723457)
GO

uspCheckSaleVIN 09872345098723457
```

Comment: What is the datatype of VIN column? You have nvarchar parameter but you're passing in a huge number -- and since the number starts with 0, that might get lost

Comment: Indeed - if `VIN` is `nvarchar` then your direct call will end up forcing the VIN to be converted to a number due to data type precedence whereas your stored proc call forces the conversion in the other direction - and probably loses the leading `0`.

Comment: You're probably right. In real life will a VIN ever begin with 0? Are there any better possibilities for my datatype?

Comment: The data type (if it's `nvarchar` or `varchar`) is probably correct - you don't expect to perform *maths* on VINs so numeric types would be wrong - where things are wrong here is when you're querying - try `uspCheckSaleVIN '09872345098723457'`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Your suggestion seems to work, but now I'm VERY curious. Why come in ALL my other stored procedures I don't need to put apostrophes around my search term? Like when I use reader.Parameters.Add("@VIN"). etc...I don't put quotes around the VIN. Does this only apply when i have only one WHERE parameter?

Comment: @d90sg98a7sdg NO, the reason is because of implicit datatype conversion. You have two examples going on here. One from SSMS and the other from code. In code it would already be a string (aka varchar). In SSMS when you don't wrap the value in tick marks it will implicitly convert the value to an int (which means no leading 0), then your procedure will implicitly convert it back to a varchar but the leading 0 is now gone.

Comment: Select out @VIn in your sproc, I bet you see that the 0 was dropped when the int you passed in was parsed to a nvarchar and that no longer matches your data where is does start with the 0.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like:

```
uspCheckSaleVIN '09872345098723457'
```

This is because 09872345098723457 is numeric and leading zero is just truncated from literal. Of course it would work only if you have non zero leading digit.

Proof:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
@p VARCHAR(5)
AS

SELECT @p

GO


EXEC test 01234
EXEC test '01234'
```

Outputs:

```
1234
01234
```

Comment: *technically*, the leading 0 is lost once the query text has been parsed  into an `int`. The later conversion from an `int` to a `varchar` doesn't see any leading zero.